# The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy

We have an application deployed on tomcat.
To access application we are using apache which sends requests to tomcat.
At random browser gives following response.

```
Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /sampleapp/<http://samplehost.com:8080/sampleapp/>.
Reason: Error reading from remote server
________________________________
Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) Server at samplehost.com Port 8080
```

This error is not coming always and so far we are getting this in a client machine with IE only. On the same client machine with Firefox it works well.

Following is the error trace from Apache logs for a failed request

```
[Thu Mar 22 02:51:08 2012] [error] [client 10.36.64.137] (20014)Internal error: proxy: error reading status line from remote server localhost:8081, referer: http://samplehost.com:8080/sampleapp/opp/showSearchHome.htm
[Thu Mar 22 02:51:08 2012] [error] [client 10.36.64.137] proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by /sampleapp/opp/searchResult.htm, referer: http://samplehost.com:8080/sampleapp/opp/showSearchHome.htm
```

Nothing is getting printed on tomcat logs when a request is failing.

Following is the information related installed version of apache

```
-bash-3.00$ ./httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix)
Server built:   Sep 21 2011 20:00:58
```

When trying to find out modules loaded I get following error

```
-bash-3.00$ /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
httpd: Syntax error on line 64 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so into server: ld.so.1: httpd: fatal: libldap-2.4.so.2: open failed: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You might want to try attempts like this in the apache configuration (try different combinations):  
//    SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1  
//    SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1  
//    SetEnv proxy-initial-not-pooled 1  
//KeepAlive Off (or On)  
Many people have similar issues with unfortunately different solutions for them. Or you try switching away from Apache to another reverse proxy.

Comment: this can occur on firefox as well, seems to be an https issue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not mentioned in you post but I suspect you are initiating an SSL connection from the browser to Apache, where VirtualHosts are configured, and Apache does a revese proxy to your Tomcat.

There is a serious bug in (some versions ?) of IE that sends the 'wrong' host information in an SSL connection (see EDIT below) and confuses the Apache VirtualHosts. In short the server name presented is the one of the reverse DNS resolution of the IP, not the one in the URL.

The workaround is to have one IP address per SSL virtual hosts/server name. Is short, you must end up with something like

1 server name == 1 IP address == 1 certificate == 1 Apache Virtual Host

**EDIT**

Though the conclusion is correct, the identification of the problem is better described here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication

Comment: So you'd be unable to host more than one SSL virtual host on the same IP? This simply can not be true, as I am doing it right now. I have several sites set up where apache2 is working solely as a proxy. 2 of the sites use SSL and it's working great. All sites are on different internal IP's, but only one public IP.

Comment: @Patrik Alienus. Did you really test your sites with browsers listed as not supporting SNI in the Wikipedia article? If it works then maybe you should correct the Wikipedia article. My personal experience is that I faced exactly this issue with customers running IE on XP.

Comment: Hmm no, the detail about SNI evaded me :/ The sites that I have running that work fine, never have a windows and/or mobile client connected to them. I actually assumed that it'd be the same in all browsers. So... n/m I guess :)

Comment: If I understand this ocrrectly this is all about SNI which means having more than one certificate with one IP address. However, there is also the SubjectAltName way or alternatively wildcard certificates where you have one IP, multiple names, and one certificate (for all names) with no need for SNI.

Comment: I think if you look at the log file entries (e.g. "referer: http://...") it is clear that SSL is not part of the question here?

Comment: this can occur in firefox as well, so not an IE-only issue. It may be SSL, however, as I have only seen the issue occur during https requests

Comment: @BGR  how to fix this problem and in which files?